# How to handle the event for Datepicker using JQuery

Tags: jquery, datepicker

In my application I am using datepicker using bootstrap. How to handle the change month/year event with Jquery. please anyone give an example for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this is worked for me to handle the events when changing other than date.

```
  $j(document).delegate('.ui-datepicker-prev', 'click', function () {
        alert("Previous Button Clicked");
  });

  $j(document).delegate('.ui-datepicker-next', 'click', function () {
        alert("next Button Clicked");
  });

  $j(document).delegate('.ui-datepicker-header', 'click', function () {
        // This is for handle header Part (including button and dropdown for month and year
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

the `changeDate` event is only for when the date is changed using the `datepicker`.

**Try something like this:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    })
    //Listen for the change even on the input
    .change(dateChanged)
    .on('changeDate', dateChanged);
});

function dateChanged(ev) {
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
    if ($('#startdate').val() != '' && $('#enddate').val() != '') {
        $('#period').text(diffInDays() + ' d.');
    } else {
        $('#period').text("-");
    }
}
```

Comment: Its Working for Date but I want to handle the event when change Month or Year